# Retrieving Delivery Steps for SMS/MMS via Twilio REST API

Tags: rest, twilio, twilio-api

Is it possible via the Twilio REST API to retrieve the Delivery Steps (like you can  see on Message Details on the Message Log)?  If it is not possible via the REST API, is there a programmatic way to get it (apart from screen scraping)?

I'm using the C# Twilio NuGet package, but I can also hit the REST API directly if necessary.  I didn't see Delivery Steps in documentation for either or by visually inspecting JSON results.  I also cannot get the Delivery Steps in the CSV export.

[image: Delivery Steps on Message Detail]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Whilst you can't get that detail from the REST API, messages in Twilio can notify you of their status as it changes.

When you send a message, just set a [`StatusCallback` parameter](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sending-messages#post-parameters-optional) and Twilio will send you an HTTP POST request when the message status changes into any of the following states: queued, failed, sent, delivered, or undelivered.

Comment: Got the same answer from Twilio support :)  I was hoping to be able to get historical data.  We currently use the StatusCallback property but it points to many different endpoints.  I'm in the middle of writing a Twilio status proxy that can receive all the status callbacks, record the information centrally, then route to the appropriate endpoint.

Comment: If anyone is curious on implementation, we've got a central library that makes Twilio calls.  I'll be converting the passed in StatusCallback URL to base 64 with a few character translations ('=' -> '@', '/' -> '-', '+' -> '_') to allow it to be a URL parameter, then specifying the URL of the proxy with the encoded endpoint URL as a parameter.  The proxy then receives the request, decodes the URL, forwards the request and then returns the response, and does central recording.

Comment: Sounds like an interesting project! Also I'm glad to see I'm on the same page as support :D

Comment: This still would be a useful feature a year later.  I understand I can timestamp the `StatusCallback` as the changes occur, but would much rather have the time directly from the source.